# Java and SWT - minimizing memory usage

Tags: java, optimization, memory-management, swt

What are nice tricks to minimize memory allocation using SWT?
I already `dispose()` everything that is no more needed, but still memory consuption is high (for a small application with a couple of Dialog and ten Composite it's ~50mb).
Is there a way to temporarily "dispose" widgets while not on focus?

This is from VisualVM. I'm not a profiling expert, so a guidance is welcome!

[image]

Comment: No, you can't temporarily dispose of controls. SWT memory usage is not usually a problem. What makes you think it is SWT using the memory rather than other parts of your code? How are you measuring memory usage? Is this the process size? The heap size?

Comment: Hi Greg! I added a VisualVM screenshot. Heap usage is very low, but still the total process memory is up to 50-60mb

Comment: @LppEdd That screenshot looks normal to me. I don't see anything remotely close to the `50-60mb` you mentioned...

Comment: I know @avojak
But if I look at TaskManager, memory goes up to what I said. But at least it remain stable.

Comment: You can't decrease the limits from command line parameters?